# Magento & Google Checkout & Tracking

Tags: magento, google-checkout

I am attempting to integrate an afilliate network with my Magento shopping cart.  I am using Google Checkout so i need to modify app/code/core/mage/googlecheckout/model/api/xml/checkout.xml in order to pass some tracking info to Google Checkout.

So far I have this code:

```
<merchant-checkout-flow-support>

        <parameterized-urls>
        <parameterized-url url="https://track.webgains.com/transaction.html?wgver=1.1&amp;wgprogramid=4449&amp;wgrs=1&amp;wgeventid=7041&amp;wgvouchercode=XXXXX"/>
            <parameters>
                <url-parameter name="wgorderreference" type="order-id"/>
                <url-parameter name="wgvalue" type="order-total"/>
            </parameters>
           </parameterized-urls>

    ....

</merchant-checkout-flow-support>
```

Does anyone know how I can replace the 'XXXXX' with the name of any discount code which has been used?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here, but have you tried adding a new attribute to the Order object called (say) `order-voucher-code` (this [forum thread](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewreply/74123/) gives you that process), and then inserting:

```
<url-parameter name="wgvouchercode" type="order-voucher-code"/>
```

That might work?